# how to configure postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, opendata

I hope you can help me. I'm trying to use open data cube (if you don't know what this is the link https://www.opendatacube.org), in the instructions to use it it's written to use postgreSql and to use postgreSql portable. Still in the instructions he says he has to configure a file called datacube.conf but I don't find it anywhere. Do I have to create it? and if you give it must be saved? Have any of you already used it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the instructions provided here:
https://datacube-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ops/db_setup.html

Install portable Postgre from the documentation link (It seems you are on Win..). After you're done, launch the portable Postgre application and paste the SQL statements highlighted in the documentation, and keep the database running.

Before starting DataCube you also have to create a configuration file by yourself *.datacube.conf* with the given content highlighted in the doc also. Preferably, create an environment variable with name DATACUBE_CONFIG_PATH for the config file so DataCube can find it. Finally, place the file to the path you specified in your environment variable.

See how to create environment variable for your system:

https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/create-custom-environment-variables-in-windows/

Comment: Thanks Bence I solved that problem. Now another one has appeared (I don't put all the errors because the space of the comment is not enough). I insert the datacube command line -v system init to initialize the database but in the end it appears to me
File "C:\Users\Mikele\Miniconda3\envs\cubeenv\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\_init_.py", line 130, in connect conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: It seems that passwordless authentication is not successful providing the user you created. To make it short cut check the username you've created before in Postgre with:
    \du
command. Then set a password for the user by:
    ALTER USER YOUR_USERNAME WITH PASSWORD 'password';
Finally, add the db_username and db_password into your _.datacube.conf_ as the documentation shows also.

Comment: I can't give you anything but i can give you my love. Thank you so much

Comment: Feel free to give a thumbs up on my comment ;)